# Collapsible menu on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code for a button that will show or hide text. Java script and html are shown below. However, I want to add multliple buttons that will do the same function, but as you can see below 'bt1' is hard-coded into the script. How can I pass a different id into the script from further buttons? I'm a Java script novice...

Thanks!!!

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id) {

if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer     \u2228')

    {
    document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer     \x3E';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer     \u2228';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

</script>
```

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td scope="col">
    <input class="bt" width="100%" type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Story &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;' onclick="setVisibility('sub3');";>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="sub3">
            <p>Loren Ipsum</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so you want two buttons one to show and one to hide right ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a refference to the clicked element using `this` keyword as follows:

```
 <input class="bt" width="100%" type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Story &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;' onclick="setVisibility(this);";>
```

then you can access the element in your function as follows:

```
function setVisibility(element) {
  // now element refers to the clicked element
  id = element.id;
  value = element.value;

  //rest of your logic
  if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer     \u2228')
  {
   document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer     \x3E';
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
  else
  {
   document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer     \u2228';
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the button as an additional parameter:

```
<input class="bt" width="100%" type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Story &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;' onclick="setVisibility(this,'sub3');">
```

JavaScript

```
function setVisibility(btn,id) {

if(btn.value=='Hide Layer     \u2228')

    {
    btn.value = 'Show Layer     \x3E';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
    btn.value = 'Hide Layer     \u2228';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass both div id and button id to the `setVisibility()` function

use this code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td scope="col">
          <input class="bt" width="100%" type=button name=type id='bt1' value='Story &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;' onclick="setVisibility('sub3',this);";>
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <div id="sub3">
                <p>Loren Ipsum</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
           </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td scope="col">
          <input class="bt" width="100%" type=button name=type id='bt2' value='Story &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;' onclick="setVisibility('sub3',this);";>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>


<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id,btn_id) {
alert(id+"   "+btn_id.id);
var button_id=btn_id.id;
if(document.getElementById(button_id).value=='Hide Layer     \u2228')

    {
    document.getElementById(button_id).value = 'Show Layer     \x3E';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById(button_id).value = 'Hide Layer     \u2228';
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

</script>
```